# Does Storm keep sending tick tuples to bolts when a topology is deactivated?

Tags: apache-storm

As part of the development of streamparse, we have a BatchingBolt that processes tuples in batches.  It's intended for use with things like databases that are more performant when you send things in batches.

I've recently proposed switching our BatchingBolt implementation over from using a timer/thread approach to using tick tuples; however, one of my fellow devs pointed out that with our current approach the final batch will definitely get processed when a topology is shutdown (and it's in the inactive state), whereas that isn't explicitly documented anywhere about tick tuples.

Therefore, my question is this:  does Storm continue sending tick tuples to bolts after a kill/deactivate has been issued, while it is in the waiting/inactive period?  The [topology lifecycle docs](http://storm.apache.org/documentation/Lifecycle-of-a-topology.html) don't make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/storm-user/201506.mbox/%3CCAF5108ijGpdMeax1LaKQ1MG6MSZQF=YM=vO8AacmN0RUiNfNkQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

AFAIK, "setup-tick!" is called from start of executor (which schedules tick timer for each executor), and tick tuples will be emitted unless worker is going to be shutdown.

In short, your fellow is correct.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! You may want to develop your answer a little and/or include a link to the Storm user group discussion you mentionned and/or any kind of reference, so that your answer can be considered canonical and of best quality. Cheers.